# automatic update of wxPython's wx.TreeCtrl

Tags: wxpython

wx.TreeCtrl is used (in wxPython) to display data from a list. How to create a tree so, that the tree view is updated (i.e. by calling wx.TreeCtrl.Refresh) if data is changed in the list?

The list itself (constructed from a database) is structured as:

```
data =  [ 'item1',
         ['item2', ['item2.1','item2.2'],],
         ['item3', [['item3.1', ['item3.1.1','item3.1.2']]]],]
```

One solution I found that kind of works is to create a virtual tree and to override Refresh as:

```
def Refresh(self):
    self.CollapseAll()
    self.Expand(self.root)
```

As the tree is virtual, on expand all the nodes are read again from the list. But overriding Refresh is probably a hack and I'm looking for a cleaner solution. There are nice examples how to do it for a grid and table (http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxPython/trunk/demo/Grid_MegaExample.py?view=markup) but I can't find anything for a tree.

**EDIT & ANSWER**

Sometimes to solve a problem it's best to formulate the question. I was using virtual tree as described in "wxPython in Action" by Rappin and Dunn. But that's a poor man's solution. Correct would be to derive a class from VirtualTree. Posting the solution here if anyone should stumble on the same problem. The solution is a pruned-down version from (http://wxwidgets2.8.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.8.8.0/TreeMixin_8py-source.html).

```
import wx
from wx.lib.mixins.treemixin import VirtualTree
items = [('item 0', [('item 2', [('a1', []),('b1', [])]), ('item 3', [])]), 
         ('item 1', [('item 4', [('a3', []),('b3', [])]), ('item 5', [])])]

class MyTree(VirtualTree, wx.TreeCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(MyTree, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.RefreshItems()
        #OnTest emulates event that causes data to change
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnTest) 
    def OnTest(self, evt): 
        items[0]=('boo', [('item 2', [('a1', []),('b1', [])]), ('item 3', [])])
        self.RefreshItems()        
    def OnGetItemText(self, index):
        return self.GetText(index)
    def OnGetChildrenCount(self, indices):
        return self.GetChildrenCount(indices)
    def GetItem(self, indices):
        text, children = 'Hidden root', items
        for index in indices: text, children = children[index]
        return text, children
    def GetText(self, indices):
        return self.GetItem(indices)[0] 
    def GetChildrenCount(self, indices):
        return len(self.GetChildren(indices))
    def GetChildren(self, indices):
        return self.GetItem(indices)[1]    

class TreeFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='wxTree Test Program')
        self.tree = MyTree(self, style=wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.TR_HIDE_ROOT)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = TreeFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most appropriate solution to this kind of problem is using the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern and, specifically, the pubsub library: [wxPython and PubSub](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/)

Comment: Observer pattern helps to improve the solution further. It makes it possible to send a message from the function that changes the data and all the trees can subscribe to this event (in the actual application there are several trees and tables that need to be updated). The solution in the question is still needed, to be able to call RefreshItems() at all. However, thanks a lot for you answer! I'm embarrassed I didn't think about the observer pattern. Currently I explicitly called all the needed refresh functions in the function that changed the data.